# Greatest n per group in a many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, greatest-n-per-group

I know there are many questions similar to this one but it seems that nothing fits my problem. I've spent quite a few hours researching this problem and came up with a query that doesn't select the last image, more on that later. So, the problem is a have 3 tables

table: images

```
| Field             | Type             
+-------------------+------------------
| id                | int(10) unsigned 
| filename          | varchar(255)    
| created_at        | timestamp
| updated_at        | timestamp
```

table: offers

```
| Field             | Type             
+-------------------+------------------
| id                | int(10) unsigned  
| message           | varchar(255)    
| created_at        | timestamp
```

and a table connecting them: offer_images

```
| Field    | Type             
+----------+------------------
| offer_id | int(10) unsigned 
| image_id | int(10) unsigned
```

So, the question is:
How do I select all offers with the last updated image (based on updated_at) from the images table that is linked to the offer. Here is what I got so far:

```
SELECT `o`.*, `i`.`filename`
FROM `offer_images` AS `oi`
INNER JOIN `offers` AS `o` on `oi`.`offer_id` = `o`.`id`
INNER JOIN `images` as `i` on `oi`.`photo_id` = `i`.`id`
GROUP BY `o`.`id`
```

The query selects everything and it's working besides that it ignores the updated_at field.

Comment: In other words, given a data set that looks like this... I want a result that looks like this...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT o.*, i.*
FROM offers AS o
INNER JOIN (
   -- Get the latest update_at date per offer_id
   SELECT oi.offer_id, MAX(updated_at) AS max_updated_at 
   FROM offer_images AS oi
   INNER JOIN images AS i ON oi.image_id = i.id
   GROUP BY oi.offer_id
) AS d ON o.id = d.offer_id
INNER JOIN offer_images AS oi ON oi.offer_id = d.offer_id
INNER JOIN images AS i ON i.id = oi.image_id AND i.updated_at = d.max_updated_at
```

The query uses a derived table to get the latest `update_at` date per `offer_id`. Using this date we can join back to the `images` table in order to get the greatest-n-per-group record.

Comment: It returns the same offers multiple times